# Bootstrap grid systems differentiate sizes in 2 types of screen sizes

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, media-queries

Im currently curious about how to differentiate my BS 3 grid in **desktop size (wider screens)** and **laptop size (smaller screens)**. For instance, currently I have a box form on center of the container like this:

```
<div className="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
  ...
</div>
```

It looks okay in **desktop (wider screens)**, it is in the middle with the same space on the right and left. But, how to make it appear full (`col-md-12`) without space on the left and right in **laptop (smaller screens)**? If I inspect the element on `devtools` in both of the devices, they are both put in a `col-md` condition of BS's `media query`, so the smaller devices will keep get the `col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 classes`.

Answer (score 0):

> Grid breakpoints are based on minimum width media queries, meaning
>   **they apply to that one breakpoint and all those above it** (e.g., `.col-sm-4` applies to small, medium, large, and extra large devices,
>   but not the first xs breakpoint)

You can **combine the classes to get the desired result for each screen size.**

**EDIT** : changed the snippet and added a full code which achieves the desired result -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


  <div class="row bg-danger" style = "height:200px;">
    <div class="col-md-0 col-lg-2"></div> <!--This will leave correct space on the sides of screen according to screen size-->
    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-8 bg-success text-center" style = "top:50px;height:50px;">
      Your box
    </div> <!--Consider this div to be your box-->
  </div>


</body>
</html>
```

The above code snippet will set the size of div to -

- 8 grids for large desktop screens( *screens equal to or greater than
  1200px wide*)
- for screens  of size - md (*for small laptops - screens equal to or
  greater than 992px wide*), it will assign 12 grids to the div.

---

You can combine the grid in similar fashion to achieve the desired results according to different screen sizes.

Hope this solves your problem !

Comment: Hi thank you for the answer. I tried it with `col-lg-8 col-md-12 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12`, but in my laptop, it looks like still get the `col-lg-8` breakpoint, not getting into `col-md-12`.

Comment: It should work. Did you try the second code snippet ?

Comment: I just tried with the first snippet, the second won't work because Im using BS 3. Btw, my laptop has `1230 x 1012px` resolution with 13" screen size. But I want to make it appear as `col-md-12` without space, the space should be only visible in desktop size.

Comment: @JustinusHermawan I have added a full code which is working just the way you require it. I have also added some extra attributes to help you visualise it. Hope this solves your problem !

Comment: Hi, here's my case https://pastebin.com/G4ew46F1, the `content` box on the right should be a `12-grids` in my laptop screen, but keep becomes `8-grids`.

Comment: @JustinusHermawan you said your laptop has 1230 x 1012px. In bootstrap 3, width greater than **1200px** is considered as lg screen and your laptop will be considered same as desktop. Bootstrap 4 introduces further segments in screen size(it provides `.col-lg` and `.col-xl` while bootstrap three only gives `.col-lg`). This is the reason it gives `8-grids` on your laptop as well.

Comment: Yes I run on macbook pro with retina which has a high enough resolution but the screen size is small, only 13". What's the recommended way to handle this case?

Comment: @JustinusHermawan I am not very experienced in bootstrap, so I don't know if there's a workaround to get your required solution. Wait and see if anyone knows how to solve this problem. My recommendation would be to switch to bootstrap 4 which allows you to differentiate between less than 992px, 992px - 1200px and greater than 1200px.

Comment: Ohh I see, it's fine. At least I've already known what's the reason. Thank you.